# 0 to Variable in Pascal

Tags: pascal

Lets take this code for example;

```
                  If (Random) <> (0 to Variable) then
```

Its very simple, I just want it to do something if Random is different than 0 to another number set in that variable, im not sure how to do this tho

Comment: Let's not. Let's post actual code, with variable declarations so we know what types you're using, and let's clearly state the question you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to check if the variable is not in range from 0 to Variable, it's better to use the code:

```
if (Random1 < 0) or (Random1 > Variable) then ...
```

I'm not sure that the code

```
if not (Random1 in [0..Variable]) then ...
```

will work for Variable values out of range [0..255]

Comment: I cant believe I didn't think of  
"if (Random1 < 0) or (Random1 > Variable) then ..."
But it works both ways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I should of explained better, they are both integer, and Random cant be used since its an instruction, it has to be Random1. 
But the answer is

"if not (Random1 in [0..Variable]) then. [0..Variable]"

Thank you very much @lurker.